# AJAX call returns undefined in Header / form-data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to get the contents from some autogenerated divs (with php) and put the contents in a php file for further processing. The reason for that is I have counters that count the number of clicks in each div. Now, I ran into a problem. When I echo back the data from the php file, the call is made, but I get undefined in the form-data section of the headers, and NULL if I do var_dump($_POST). I am almost certain I am doing something wrong with the AJAX call. I am inexperienced to say the least in AJAX or Javascript. Any ideas? The code is pasted below. Thanks for any help / ideas.
The AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("form[ajax=true]").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form_data = $(this).find(".test");
        var form_url = $(this).attr("action");
        var form_method = $(this).attr("method").toUpperCase();
        $.ajax({
            url: form_url, 
            type: form_method,      
            data: form_data,     
            cache: false,
            success: function(returnhtml){                          
                $("#resultcart").html(returnhtml); 
            }           
        });    

    });

});
```

The PHP is a simple echo. Please advise.

Comment: `data` needs to be a plain object or query string, you set it to a jQuery object. Take a look at jQuery's [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method

Comment: `$(this).find(".test")` returns jQuery object. If you need value - `$(this).find(".test").val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a div

```
<div id="send_me">
    <div class="sub-item">Hello, please send me via ajax</div>
    <span class="sub-item">Hello, please send me also via ajax</span>
</div>
```

Make AJAX request like

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'get_sorted_content.php',
    type: 'POST', // GET is default
    data: {
        yourData: $('#send_me').html()
        // in PHP, use $_POST['yourData']
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        alert('Data returned from PHP: ' + msg);
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        alert('AJAX request failed!' + msg);
    }
});
```

Now in PHP, you can access this data passed in the following manner

```
<?php
// get_sorted_content.php
if(!empty($_POST['yourdata']))
    echo 'data received!';
else
    echo 'no data received!';
?>
```

Comment: mrid, thanks for the advice. But it doesn't seem to work. The idea is to get all the content from a <div>, and send it to that PHP file. This is the issue. Should I enclose the whole php bit which generates the content inside of the <div> and place it in a dummy form? I need my data to be like this: <div> someinfo</div>; <div>someotherinfo</div>; when I am storing it in PHP for further processing...

Comment: No need to make a dummy form. You can directly sent the `div` html. I've updated my code

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. I will try to learn it better before posting. Really, thanks. I owe you a beer...

Comment: np bud..Glad to know it helped :)

Comment: Ah, one more thing. I noticed that it only takes the first div in the send-me div. How can I take all of the div's that are the children of send-me?

Comment: It's taking the entire div content when I tried it. Want me to upload a sample for you ?

Comment: My div structure is messed up from the trials I've done. Rebuilding now. Thanks for the pen :)

Comment: What did you have in your php file? How do you interpret the data? Is it JSON, urldecode?

Comment: Sorted. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's sorted. Thanks to everyone. The problem was I didn't respect the pattern parent -> child of the divs. All I needed to do was to wrap everything in another div. I really didn't know this was happening because I was echoing HTML code from PHP.